# Projection of WMS in MapInfo

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, mapinfo

I am using the OSM open Roads WMS layer that comes included with MapInfo. I have noticed that when I load this layer the projection of the Map window changes to 'Popular Visualization CRS.'

All the other layers I use are set to British National Grid. Is there a way to change the projection of the WMS layer so it matches British National Grid?

Answer (score 2):

Currently MapInfo Pro doesn't let you change the projection of a map window, when the map contains a Tile Server layer.

On our Ideas Portal you can find [a request](http://ideas.pb.com/ideaView?id=08780000000E4NmAAK) to change this.

One solution would be to find an OSM tile server that does provide the OSM data using British National Grid.

With MapInfo Pro v2021, this has changed. You can now change the coordinate system of map holding tile server or WMTS tables too. Read more in this article: [MapInfo Monday: Web Service Improvements in MapInfo Pro v2021](https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=19&MessageKey=915947c1-803a-41df-a433-fad0f481f2a9)